# Call variable in function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have name.PHP file in which following code is present:

```
<?php  $trans=pll_e('All Products'); ?>
```

Here `pll_e('All Products')` is a plugin's function which is useful for translate string.Above code will give Output as `All Products` if language is English or else it will give output `Other language`.

In that name.PHP file, there is function.

Code for that function:

```
function catalogue() {

if($count>0){
        $return_string .= '<li class="wpc-category ' . $class . '"><a href="'. get_option('catalogue_page_url') .'">All Products</a></li>'; 
        foreach($termsCatSort as $term){
            if($term_slug==$term->slug){
            $class  =   'active-wpc-cat';
        }else{
            $class  =   '';
        }
        $return_string .=  '<li class="wpc-category '. $class .'"><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'wpccategories').'">'. $term->name .'</a></li>';    
        }
    }else{
        $return_string .=  '<li class="wpc-category"><a href="#">No category</a></li>'; 
    }
}
```

I want to use `$trans` in that **function** in place of **All Products** .How can I do that ?

Comment: Declare $trans global and use it anywhere

Comment: Use one of the below suggestions. They should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made mistake in using plugin's default option.

I was using `pll_e('All Products')` but when I used `pll__('All Products')` it worked .

Answer (score 0):

```
$trans=pll_e('All Products');

function catalogue($trans) {

  if($count>0){
    $return_string .= '<li class="wpc-category ' . $class . '"><a href="'. get_option('catalogue_page_url') .'">'.$trans.'</a></li>'; 
    foreach($termsCatSort as $term){
        if($term_slug==$term->slug){
        $class  =   'active-wpc-cat';
    }else{
        $class  =   '';
    }
    $return_string .=  '<li class="wpc-category '. $class .'"><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'wpccategories').'">'. $term->name .'</a></li>';    
    }
  }else{
    $return_string .=  '<li class="wpc-category"><a href="#">No category</a></li>'; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a variable to the function:

```
function catalogue($trans) {
  echo $trans;
}
```

or you can make the variable accessible within the function using "global":

```
function catalogue() {
  global $trans;
  echo $trans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as follows if $trans is defined before function..

```
function catalogue($trans) 
{
  if($count>0)
  {
    $return_string .= '<li class="wpc-category ' . $class . '"><a href="'. get_option('catalogue_page_url') .'">'.$trans.'</a></li>'; 
    foreach($termsCatSort as $term)
    {
        if($term_slug==$term->slug)
        {
          $class  =   'active-wpc-cat';
        }else{
          $class  =   '';
        }
        $return_string .=  '<li class="wpc-category '. $class .'"><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'wpccategories').'">'. $term->name .'</a></li>';    
    }
  }
  else
  {
     $return_string .=  '<li class="wpc-category"><a href="#">No category</a></li>'; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not relly a point in storing every possible translatable string in a variable, just so you can use it maybe later. Just call the translation function where you need it.

```
$return_string .= '<li class="wpc-category ' . $class . '"><a href="'. get_option('catalogue_page_url') .'">'. pll_e('All Products') . '</a></li>'; 
// ...
$return_string .=  '<li class="wpc-category"><a href="#">' . pll_e('No category') . '</a></li>';
```

Answer (score -1):

you can describe params for function and also have default value, if parameter was not passed

```
function catalogue($trans = 'All Products') {

if($count>0){
        $return_string .= '<li class="wpc-category ' . $class . '"><a href="'. get_option('catalogue_page_url') .'">'.$trans.'</a></li>'; 
        foreach($termsCatSort as $term){
            if($term_slug==$term->slug){
            $class  =   'active-wpc-cat';
        }else{
            $class  =   '';
        }
        $return_string .=  '<li class="wpc-category '. $class .'"><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'wpccategories').'">'. $term->name .'</a></li>';    
        }
    }else{
        $return_string .=  '<li class="wpc-category"><a href="#">No category</a></li>'; 
    }
}
```

so if you do:

```
catalogue(); // All Products will be used
```

else

```
$trans=pll_e('All Products');
catalogue($trans);
```

but Also you can use in function without passing parametrers

```
function catalogue() {

    if($count>0){

        $trans = pll_e('All Products');

        $return_string .= '<li class="wpc-category ' . $class . '"><a href="'. get_option('catalogue_page_url') .'">'.$trans.'</a></li>'; 
        foreach($termsCatSort as $term){
            if($term_slug==$term->slug){
            $class  =   'active-wpc-cat';
        }else{
            $class  =   '';
        }
        $return_string .=  '<li class="wpc-category '. $class .'"><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'wpccategories').'">'. $term->name .'</a></li>';    
        }
    }else{
        $return_string .=  '<li class="wpc-category"><a href="#">No category</a></li>'; 
    }
}
```